# How can I downgrade Magento EE 2.4 to CE

Tags: magento2, migration, opensource, downgrade

I want to move from the Magento commerce version to the open-source version, I have version 2.4.1.

Any help regarding how to do this?

Comment: Did you find any good solution?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Did you get any proper solution ?